# How to store data in a CSV file to a structure and then return that structure

Tags: c, arrays, csv, malloc, structure

This is my first post at stack overflow, and hope someone is able to point me in the correct direction. I am writing a C funtion where my goal is to read a csv file. The data in the file is then passed to an structure array, which I then would like to return to a function call in main(), accessing the data for further use. How do I properly read and then return the complete structure array?

This function is an addon to an existing PLC program, where at the moment all system parameters is stored in retain memory. The goal is to read/write parameters to a CSV file for backup.I suspect that I am doing something wrong in the while loop, but are at this point not able to figure out what. It could also be I am not using pointers correctly. The CSV file looks like this:

```
2;motor nominal current;1700
3;motor nominal speed;2500.0
4;motor nominal power;1200.0
5;motor nominal voltage;690.0
6;Enable motor heating;TRUE
7;Motor heating time on;40.0
```

I am by the way aware that I don`t free the memory allocated in the function. This will be handled further on.

Here is the program containing the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BSIZE 80

struct parameter{
    int id;
    char *name;
    char *value;
};

struct parameter* readCSV(const char *file)
{
    char buffer[BSIZE];
    FILE *f;
    char *field;

    // open the CSV file
    f = fopen(file,"r");
    if( f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file '%s'\n",file);
        exit(1);
    }
    static struct parameter *parameters[BSIZE];

        int i = 0;
    // read the data
    while(fgets(buffer,BSIZE,f) != NULL)
    {
        parameters[i] =(struct parameter*)malloc(sizeof(struct parameter));

         // get id
        field = strtok(buffer,";");
        parameters[i]->id = atoi(field);

        // get name
        field = strtok(NULL,";");
        parameters[i]->name = field;

        // get value
        field = strtok(NULL,";");
        parameters[i]->value = field;

        // display the result
        printf("ID%d:\t%s\t%s\n",parameters[i].id, parameters[i].name, parameters[i].value);

        i++;
    }

    //close file
    fclose(f);

    return *parameters;

}

int main()
{
    struct parameter *parameters;

    parameters = readCSV("QD_Config.csv");

        printf("ID%d:\t%s\t%s\n",parameters[0]->id, parameters[0]->name, parameters[0]->value);

    return(0);
}
```

I am able to print the contents of the file, but am not able to properly store the structure array before passing it it seems. In main(), when calling the function, I only get the last name and value in the file, but with the ID number of the first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you (probably) have is that the [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function returns a pointer to the string you're tokenizing. It does not create a new string for you.

That means e.g.

```
field = strtok(NULL,";");
parameters[i]->name = field;
```

will make `parameters[i]->name` point to some character in `buffer`. And once the function `readCSV` returns the variable `buffer` ends its life-time and ceases to exist, leaving you with invalid pointer.

You need to allocate memory for the strings yourself and copy the data to them. This is either done by making the structure members arrays and use `strcpy` to copy the string to these arrays, or by using the non-standard but commonly available `strdup` function (which allocates memory dynamically of the heap and copies the string to it).

---

There's another problem related to returning your structures:

```
return *parameters;
```

is equal to

```
return parameters[0];
```

That is, you return a pointer to a single `parameter` structure.

If you want to return the whole array, you should do

```
return parameters;  // Return the whole array
```

But note that it will decay to a pointer to its first element (i.e. `&parameters[0]`) which have the type `struct parameter **`, so you need to adjust the return type appropriately.

You also need to initialize `parameters` to null-pointers, or otherwise it's going to be hard to find the end of the array:

```
static struct parameter *parameters[BSIZE] = { NULL };
```

However a better solution which I rather recommend, is that you pass in the array as an argument, and return the number of elements you fill in. Then you can use an array of structure objects (instead of an array of structure pointers) and don't have to do any dynamic allocation and risk memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented strcpy(). e.g. strcpy(parameters[i]).id, field); and changed the structure members to string arrays. e.g. char id[45]. But the return value is still empty. I clearly need to read some more on the topic. I am probably not allocating correctly still.

Comment: @T.Strand Updated with the `return` problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BSIZE 80

struct parameter{
    int id;
    char *name;
    char *value;
    struct parameter *next;//If you dont sure how many lins in csv you need this
};
typedef struct parameter parameter;
//I'm lazy too type struct
parameter* CreateNewQ_Q(){
    parameter *Q_Q=(parameter*)malloc(sizeof(parameter));
    Q_Q->name=NULL;//Nothing at first
    Q_Q->value=NULL;//Nothing at first
    Q_Q->next=NULL;//Nothing at first
    return Q_Q;
}
void readCSV(const char *file,parameter *Q_Q)
{
    char buffer[BSIZE];
    FILE *f;
    char *field;
    parameter* A_A=Q_Q;
    // open the CSV file
    f = fopen(file,"r");
    if( f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file '%s'\n",file);
        exit(1);
    }


    // read the data
    while(fgets(buffer,BSIZE,f) != NULL)
    {
        if(A_A->next==NULL){//Next Nothing So Create after it
            A_A->next=CreateNewQ_Q();
        }
        A_A=A_A->next;//A_A is New A_A now
         // get id
        field = strtok(buffer,";");
        A_A->id = atoi(field);

        // get name
        field = strtok(NULL,";");
        //Q_Q
            //<--------Here alloc memory for your name because strtok not alloc new memory it just return a pointer in buffer[?]-------------->
            A_A->name=(char *)malloc((sizeof(strlen(field)+1)*sizeof(char)));//+1 Becuz '\0' at end of string is necessary
            //<--------Here Copy Result-------------->
            strcpy(A_A->name, field);
        //Q_Q

        // get value
        field = strtok(NULL,";");
        //Q_Q
            //<--------Here alloc memory for your value because strtok not alloc new memory it just return a pointer in buffer[?]-------------->
            A_A->value=(char *)malloc((sizeof(strlen(field)+1)*sizeof(char)));//+1 Becuz '\0' at end of string is necessary
            //<--------Here Copy Result-------------->
            strcpy(A_A->value, field);
        //Q_Q

        // display the result
        printf("ID%d:\t%s\t%s\n",A_A->id, A_A->name, A_A->value);

    }

    //close file
    fclose(f);



}
void DeleteAllQ_Q(parameter *Q_Q){
    if(Q_Q->next){
        DeleteAllQ_Q(Q_Q->next);
        Q_Q->next=NULL;
    }else{
        free(Q_Q->name);//I dont have next so i'm free
        free(Q_Q->value);
        free(Q_Q);
    }

}
int main()
{
    //memory control is important!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    parameter *parameters=CreateNewQ_Q();

    readCSV("QD_Config.csv",parameters);
    printf("Ok Load Done A_A\n");
    for(parameter *loopQ_Q=parameters->next;loopQ_Q!=NULL;loopQ_Q=loopQ_Q->next){
        printf("ID%d:\t%s\t%s\n",loopQ_Q->id, loopQ_Q->name, loopQ_Q->value);
    }


    DeleteAllQ_Q(parameters);//free parameters's next and next's next and....
    free(parameters);//free self

    return(0);
}
```

I spend sometime, i think this method control memory is more safe!

Comment: Appreciate your contribution. I agree that a linked list would normally be a good solution, because the parameter list may grow in size over time. But I have not yet found a good solution to how I would be able to implement support for it in the PLC application. I also don't worry about collisions as the ID 's are unique for each parameter and will set the index of the structure array.